# How many times has the Ethereum mining difficulty bomb been pushed back?

Tags: mining, difficulty-bomb

Ethereum has a built in mining difficulty bomb to force an upgrade. How many times have the difficulty bomb been pushed out? And by pushing out this mining bomb, doesn't this create more ETH into the ecosystem?